# middleman server error with 'listen' 3.0.3 gem instead of 2.10.1

Tags: bundler, middleman

I'm running on windows 8.1 and try to run 'middleman server' (with gem version 2.4.8 and Middleman version 3.3.12). When doing so I get the following error (see below appendix for full error message): " You have already activated listen 3.0.3, but your Gemfile requires listen 2.10.1"

Yet the gem 'Listen' is not explicitely written in my gemfile, must be a dependency with something else.

So what I did was to explicitely add in my gemfile :

```
gem 'listen', '~> 2.10.1'
```

And then run again

```
$bundle install
```

Yet when I run again '$middleman server' it does not work. So in my terminal I check which version of 'listen' gem I have and see that it's :

```
C:\Users\Edouard\Desktop\stylus>bundle show listen
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/listen-2.10.1
```

Would someone have a lead on how to solve that ? Because I don't have a clue..

Appendix - The whole error message I get is :

```
C:\Users\Edouard\Desktop\stylus>middleman server
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
rack (< 2.0, >= 1.0, >= 1.0.0, >= 1.4.5)
uber (~> 0.0.4)
activesupport (>= 3.1, ~> 4.1)
ffi (>= 0.5.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated listen 3.0.3, but your Gem
file requires listen 2.10.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.0/lib/middleman-core/load_paths.rb:29:in `setup_load_paths'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.0/bin/middleman:10:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22/bin/middleman:23:in `load'
from C:/Ruby22/bin/middleman:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is apparently linked to the gem middleman-deploy on windows 8.1. 
Here is the solution I apply using github :

- remove middleman-deploy from gemfile
- in the same folder than the gemfile create a rakefile (without any extension) on which you put require     `'middleman gh-pages'`
- then after you made some changes to your work, do a `commit` on master branch
- then do `rake publish`

Answer (score 0):

I had same trouble: `middleman server error with 'listen' 3.0.3 gem instead of 2.10.1`.

Try remove /Gemfile.lock and exec `bundle install`.

That worked for me.